# In python, how do I create two index slicing for my own matrix class?

Tags: python, matrix, slice, magic-methods

I am trying to write my own matrix class in python, just for testing purposes. In reality, this matrix class is in c++ and I am using SWIG to interface between the two. However, for this question, it might be simpler to consider a pure python implementation of this matrix class.

I want to be able to call this matrix class and use two-indexed slicing. For example, after we create 4x4 matrix of ones,

```
>>> A = Matrix(4,4,1)
```

I want to be able to get the sub 2x2 matrix:

```
>>>> A[1:2,1:2]
```

I've heard of the `__getslice__` method, but this seems like it only allows single slicing, e.g. `A[1:2]`. So how can perform a two-index slicing so I can call `A[i:j,l:k]`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Note that `__getslice__` is deprecated since version 2.0.

So consider the following minimal example:

```
class Foo:
    def __getitem__(self, *args):
        print args
f = Foo()
f[1:2,2:4]
```

This will print:

```
((slice(1, 2, None), slice(2, 4, None)),)
```

If you have a look at the [data model docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html), you'll see that `slice` objects are:

> ...used to represent slices when extended slice syntax is used.
>   Special read-only attributes: `start` is the lower bound; `stop` is the
>   upper bound; `step` is the step value; each is `None` if omitted. These
>   attributes can have any type.

From here it should be pretty clear how to implement your 2 index slice handling.

Comment: I see. So you pass a tuple of slice objects. Cool, thanks! Now, do you happen to know how to pass a tuple of slice objects via the python-c API?

Comment: No sorry, although I don't see why it'd be different from other methods. It's just standard arg passing with slices?